# How to check if an org (sub)heading is a link to certain file types

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I need to check if an org sub(heading) is a link to a file with a certain file type or not (for example only images of type `png` or `jpg`. I have no idea how to check if a string links to a file.

An example of a header

> * [[/path/to/image.png]["this image"]]

What I have now in pseudocode.

```
(defun mp/org-expand-img-header ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-item) (cdr (assoc "ITEM" (org-entry-properties))))
    (when (eq (current-item) ??is-link??)
      (eq (?get-file-extension? (current-item)) ??is-in-extenstion-list??))))
```

Am I on the correct way to check if it's a link?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info - `elisp` is *almost never* a good tag to use: it has a specific meaning as described in the link above and it is *not* meant for questions that just include some snippets of `elisp` (after all, many, if not most, questions on the Emacs SE are bound to include such a snippet: using the tag for all such questions would make it useless for searching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to use `M-x org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`) and then choose `file:` when creating the header (if you are visiting the buffer of some file, then you can quickly store a `file:` link using `M-x org-store-link, and subsequently insert it using` org-insert-link`, see section [Handling Links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-Links.html) of the Org manual).

Anyway, also without using the above, you can use the following function to check if something is a file link

```lisp
(defun org-file-link-p ()
  (let ((context (org-element-context)))
    (and (eq (car context) 'link)
         (string= (org-element-property :type context) "file")
         (member (file-name-extension (org-element-property :path context))
                 '("jpg" "png")))))
```

the cursor should be placed inside the link to work correctly.

If you'd like to determine it while the cursor is on a headline, but not on over the link, then you should jump to the headline title first, e.g. using:

```lisp
(defun org-headline-jump-to-title ()
  (let (title-end)
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (let ((context (org-element-context)))
    (when (eq (car context) 'headline)
        (let ((raw-value (org-element-property :raw-value context)))
          (setq title-end (search-forward raw-value))))))
    (if title-end
    (goto-char title-end)
      (message "Not on a headline"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I already use `C-c C-l` to place the links. `org-element-context` was the one I need. I'm iterating over all the headers with `org-map-entries` so your first snippet should be enough

Comment: Could you just add a check if the filetype is part of some list of filetypes? I'm only interested in the headings if it links to an `jpg` or `png`.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer. However, it would be great if you could (still) update your question, instead of 'extending' it via a comment. B.t.w., for the check, you could also use `image-supported-file-p` if you'd like to include all 'supported' image types. Finally, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark on the left (if you think it's appropriate).

Comment: It was already in the question? I just updated the title as it was not clear. Thanks for the update.  Smart as well to maybe put it in a seperate `image-supported-file-p` function.
-- Yes! I was just waiting for you to add the file extension check.